# FileNotFoundException in android

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception, file-not-found

I have a pice of code, which streams video from server, to flash player which I inserted in my app, but sometimes, after user press "play" due to network problem, it gets an FileNotFoundException. how can i edit my code to try and tray and tray a din, until, server respond?
this is my code:

```
    irib1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            rtmpUrl = "rtmp://live.kashef.tv/totalstreamer";
            fileName = "irib1-"+ qpm +".sdp";

            if (fileName.endsWith(".flv")) {
                fileName = "flv:" + fileName;
            }

            bodyHtml = htmlCode;
            bodyHtml = bodyHtml.replaceAll("@FILESRC@", 
                    "\"file=" + fileName
                    + "&streamer=" + rtmpUrl + "\"");
            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://127.0.0.1",
                    htmlPre + bodyHtml
                    + htmlPost, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

        }
    });
```

and this is my LogCat:

```
11-24 19:48:01.380: W/System.err(17187): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://live.kashef.tv/fcs/ident2
11-24 19:48:01.380: W/System.err(17187):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
11-24 19:48:01.380: W/System.err(17187):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
11-24 19:48:01.380: W/System.err(17187):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: I got `The requested URL could not be retrieved` when I tried to access `http://live.kashef.tv/fcs/ident2` directly using Chrome. Is the server down?

Comment: I extracted 'rtpm'address and file name from this url [link](view-source:http://live.irib.ir/playerFlash.php?cat_id=3&type=64&dif=0)